# Using assign_attributes with nested strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What would be the correct way to pass in the `:verification_status` enum of the `user_attributes` of `practice_user_params` into the assign attributes method? This is what I currently have:

```
@practice_user.assign_attributes({:verification_status => User.verification_statuses[:user_not_verified]})

def practice_user_params
   params.require(:practice_user).permit(:role, user_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :verification_status])
end
```